# How to pass a null value from HTML form to mysql db foreign key field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have two tables: parent and child. One of the child column references parent PRIMARY KEY with FOREIGN KEY constraint - child.parent_id references parent.parent_id.

Foreign key column in child tables allows NULLs values because when child will be created parent may be not known yet. But when info about parent will be assigned/updated i want to have referential integrity.

And now the question:

How to pass null value from HTML form to MySQL? Quotes '' or "" not working "foreign key constraint fails" probably because it passes empty string instead of null value. Or maybe do I need to do some additional checking in PHP and convert it to null ?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parent` (
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `child` (
 `child_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `child_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`child_id`),
 KEY `fk_parent_id` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `child`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_parent_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `parent` (`parent_id`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your empty value to null or edit your query in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to pass up a `NULL` value when your tables do not support `NULL` values in the parent? Also

```
`parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Should be `NOT NULL` as a child should always have a parent.

If you are trying to pass parent/child identifiers from a HTML form, I would recommend validating them server side in your `PHP` code.  As I could easily manipulate the values in the markup and add any parent/child combination I wish.

Comment: I want to allow null value in the child table because the parent may still be unknown during child creation and the relation will be created later. I've omitted validation for sake of simplicity and validation won't convert it.

Comment: @czomberzdaniela - you can't do that. You have a foreign key constraint that states that `parent_id` in the child table must reference an ID in the parent table.  If you create a child record without a valid parent id then the constraint will be violated.

Comment: Yes You can. INSERT INTO `foreign_test`.`child` (`child_id`, `child_name`, `parent_id`) VALUES (NULL, 'Jack', NULL); works fine. You can also do this from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @czomberzdaniela - does `foreign test` have a foreign key on parent_id that is referencing the parent table?

Comment: yes of course: ALTER TABLE `child`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_parent_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `parent` (`parent_id`);